# Testing accessibility using Mac VoiceOver for web pages

Tags: html, macos, testing, accessibility, text-to-speech

I am working on developing/testing accessibility of a web page using VoiceOver [Mac Tool].

Typical workflow I am using is trial and error,

1. Do changes to HTML
2. Open page in browser
3. Turn on VoiceOver and test and again #1

What I understand is VoiceOver convert/see HTML/Webpage in text form and starts reading it. I hope how it does it would make it easy for me to understand how to make process easy.

So I want to know if there is any tool or utility or guidelines which could assist me to see HTML/Webpage the way VoiceOver does. I mean tool which take html as input and then output text file like VoiceOver (JUST to understand what changes affects VoiceOver in what way quickly).

Any inputs will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebAIM has a great article titled [Using VoiceOver to Evaluate Web Accessibility](http://webaim.org/articles/voiceover/)

It helps by telling you how to get set up, what keys are used, how users navigate, how to test images, tables, and other elements.

Testing with any screen reader is about more than tabbing through the page as you watch. Ideally you want to get to the point where you can turn off your screen and test. You must also recognize that most VO users do not tab through a page, but instead tend to jump around by landmarks, headings, links, lists, and so on.

I am not pasting the entire article, but here is the outline:

- [Introduction](http://webaim.org/articles/voiceover/#intro)
- [Getting Started](http://webaim.org/articles/voiceover/#getting)
- [Reading](http://webaim.org/articles/voiceover/#reading)
- [Navigation](http://webaim.org/articles/voiceover/#navigation)

  - [Other useful shortcut keys](http://webaim.org/articles/voiceover/#shortcuts)
- [Images](http://webaim.org/articles/voiceover/#images)
- [Data Tables](http://webaim.org/articles/voiceover/#tables)
- [Forms](http://webaim.org/articles/voiceover/#forms)
- [Practice](http://webaim.org/articles/voiceover/#practice)
- [VoiceOver on the iPhone, iPod Touch, and iPad](http://webaim.org/articles/voiceover/#mobile)

Answer (score 2):

Chrome Dev tools has an Accessibility Properties panel, which will show you the accessible name of an item the way it is exposed to the VoiceOver API. It would be quicker to keep that panel open and only test in VoiceOver when you are happy with what you're seeing in the panel.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, it sounds like you're looking for the [Accessibility inspector](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/OSXAXTestingApps.html) tool, which exposes the accessibility API (OSX Safari uses [NSAccessibility](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsaccessibility) and iOS Safari uses [UIAccessibility](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/1657063-uiaccessibility) for iOS) bits (which VoiceOver consumes). This is part of Xcode, so you'll need Xcode on your Mac to get to it